# C++ Macro Code - Explicit integer (of any size) conversion to a pointer type

Tags: c++, macros, casting, avr

**Problem:**
I am interfacing to AVR code that has a pre-existing macro in place...

```
#define pgm_read_float_near(address_short) foo
```

It is used to take in a `uint16_t` value as a pointer, fetch it then return a `float` value. I am using an x86 processor with a flat address space, and I only need this macro to deference the pointer. My goal is a very explicit cast from a `uint16_t` to a `float *` before dereferencing it.

**Current Solution:**

```
#define pgm_read_float_near(address_short) *reinterpret_cast<float *>(reinterpret_cast<void *>(NULL) | static_cast<uint16_t>(address_short))
```

What I am attempting to do..

1. `static_cast` whatever variable that is given to the macro (not type
   safe) as a uint16_t, which I am expecting
2. `OR` that value with a
   "`NULL` pointer", to "cleanly" expand the `uint16_t` to the
   `uint32_t`
3. `reinterpret_cast` the result of the `OR` back into a `float *`
4. Finally, deference the `float *` to get the `float` value.

**Question:**

1. Am I forgetting any steps?
2. Am I doing any unnecessary steps, and why?

**NOTE:** Before you say, "Macros are horrible!" I have no choice, I'm working in an existing framework...

Comment: If you want a `uint32_t`, why aren't steps 1 and 2 replaced with a static_cast to `uint32_t`?

Comment: This is exactly what my question is surrounding. I fear macros, because they are not typed, so I am trying to avoid unexpected bits. The macro is expecting a uint16_t, so I am trying to make sure it is getting what it is expecting. This may or may not be necessary, I don't know or I wouldn't have asked.

Comment: What makes you think that a 16-bit value when promoted to a 32-bit pointer type will point to any meaningful location? Are you coding x86 'bare metal'? If not, how can you make sure the `float` you're accessing is actually present within the first 64kb of the process's address space?

Comment: @HannoBinder Great feedback! (+1) As I stated, I am working with AVR code and it was designed this way. I am trying to port it to x86. Your concern echoes one of my own. The point of this SO question is to get the translation of the pointer handled as "correctly" as possible. The next steps will require independent testing on the code I'm porting over, to see if this strategy will pan out or bust. Thank you for your careful consideration, that's why I turned to SO!

Comment: By the way, another proposal: `uint8_t bytes[]; float* ptr = (float*)( (void*)(&bytes[myInt]) );`

Comment: This gives me another idea: Maybe you can represent/emulate the AVR's RAM as an array of bytes, like `union { uint8_t avrRam[AVR_RAM_SIZE]; struct { uint8_t avrGlobalVariable1; char avrGlobalVariable2; ... } };`. This way, you know the exact location of the memory area where the AVR would store it's data and can index the byte array (emulated RAM) with a `uint16_t`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using C++, I would suggest using C++ template:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

template<class Ty>
float *explicit_cast(Ty t) {
    return 2;
}

template<>
float *explicit_cast<uint16_t>(uint16_t t) {
    return reinterpret_cast<float *>(t);
}

#define pgm_read_float_near(address_short) explicit_cast(address_short)

void t8() {
    uint8_t f8 = 2;
    pgm_read_float_near(f8);
}

void t16() {
    uint16_t f16 = 2;
    pgm_read_float_near(f16);
}

void t32() {
    uint32_t f32 = 2;
    pgm_read_float_near(f32);
}
```

By compiling the program, you can see the following output:

```
$ g++ cast.cpp -c
cast.cpp: In instantiation of ‘float* explicit_cast(Ty) [with Ty = unsigned char]’:
cast.cpp:18:5:   required from here
cast.cpp:6:12: error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘float*’ [-fpermissive]
cast.cpp: In instantiation of ‘float* explicit_cast(Ty) [with Ty = unsigned int]’:
cast.cpp:28:5:   required from here
cast.cpp:6:12: error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘float*’ [-fpermissive]
```

Casting from other type will introduce compiling error. The principle is that we can use the template to distinguish between uint16_t and other types.

Comment: I really like your use of templating! I am curious, does my example above not do the same kind of type checking when I use the `static_cast<uint16_t>(address_short)`?

Comment: @Zak `static_cast` does __not__ check the source type (either in compiling time or runtime). It is simply a [type convertsion](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/) template.